# Accessing wireless network through terminal in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terminal, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm connected to a wireless network and it's working fine on browser but not on terminal. I'm getting a timeout error when i'm trying to download any plugin for ruby

Comment: Should this go to superuser.com?

Comment: try sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have specified the gateway and DNS server IPs correctly. Also make Firefox use these settings. Then try it in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sources.list comes with an error,or you can change the ubuntu sources mirror and then update to try again